# What average precision is the plot_precision_recall_curve() function plotting?

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

After using the plot_precision_recall_curve() from scikit learn I was wondering what average precision this function is using. When looking in the docs, this is what I find for a binary target:

```
# %%
# Compute the average precision score
# ...................................
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
average_precision = average_precision_score(y_test, y_score)

print('Average precision-recall score: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      average_precision))
```

This is my data:

```
clf_4 = svm.SVC()
clf_4.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_clf_4 = clf_4.predict(X_test)

y1_test = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

y1_clf4 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

average_precision_5 = average_precision_score(y1_test, y1_clf4)
average_precision_5
Out: 0.5625
```

Now we use the plot_precision_recall_curve with X_test being this (same as above):

```
X_test= np.array([[0.01167537, 0.04676259, 0.02145552, 0.015625  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.5       , 0.01020408, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00478415, 0.01258993, 0.06759886, 0.09375   , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.43421053, 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.01503446, 0.04136691, 0.02600806, 0.015625  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.13157895, 0.02721088, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.017396  , 0.04856115, 0.07737383, 0.046875  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.44736842, 0.04421769, 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.0072882 , 0.01079137, 0.07866155, 0.078125  , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.63157895, 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00733909, 0.0323741 , 0.0487578 , 0.046875  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.44736842, 0.02040816, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.02579371, 0.11151079, 0.03639438, 0.0625    , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.53947368, 0.02380952, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00203581, 0.03417266, 0.12611863, 0.125     , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.05263158, 0.00680272, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00527275, 0.03057554, 0.0344563 , 0.03125   , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.09210526, 0.00680272, 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00590385, 0.02158273, 0.05135926, 0.046875  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.43421053, 0.00340136, 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.01910608, 0.16366906, 0.05917014, 0.03125   , 1.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.28947368, 0.12244898, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.12737045, 0.13669065, 0.07280827, 0.078125  , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.46052632, 0.07823129, 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.0537861 , 0.17446043, 0.14109651, 0.078125  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.32894737, 0.08843537, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.01027066, 0.05755396, 0.06110172, 0.078125  , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.30263158, 0.01360544, 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.0085504 , 0.01978417, 0.03185484, 0.03125   , 1.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.51315789, 0.00340136, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.02224122, 0.05215827, 0.06370968, 0.0625    , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.47368421, 0.04081633, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00896774, 0.05035971, 0.00974896, 0.015625  , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.5       , 0.02721088, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.03302084, 0.07014388, 0.00779787, 0.015625  , 1.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.25      , 0.03741497, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00630083, 0.06115108, 0.01495838, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.10526316, 0.00340136, 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.00951741, 0.03776978, 0.13261576, 0.140625  , 1.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 0.47368421, 0.0170068 , 1.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]])
```

Now we can use the plot_precision_recall_curve function and print the two results, and they differ:

```
disp = plot_precision_recall_curve(clf_4, X_test, y1_test)
disp.ax_.set_title(f'2-class Precision-Recall curve:{average_precision_5}')
```

[image]

So where does the difference come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `y_score` parameter of `average_precision_score` needs to be probability estimates (or a similar continuous score), not the hard classification results.  So your `average_precision_5` is incorrect.